# How to use javascript to grab image base on the result of a serie of selection menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a starter on HTML and JavaScript, I'm a design student working on a project and I need to make a website. Now I was gaining difficulties on how to create a JavaScript function that can grab images from folder base on the result of 3 selection menus.

Currently the JavaScript is like this:

```
window.ChangeOverlayMap=function(imgPtr){
    var map1obj= document.getElementById("map1")
    var map1value= map1obj.options[Index].value

    var blendmodeobj= document.getElementById("blendmode")
    var blendmodevalue= blendmodeobj.options[Index].value

    var map2obj= document.getElementById("map2")
    var map2value= map2obj.options[Index].value

    if(map1value="0"){
        if(blendmodevalue="0"){
            if(map2value="0"){
                document.getElementById('OverlayMap').src = "Img/000.png";
            }else
            if(map2value="1"){
                document.getElementById('OverlayMap').src = "Img/000.png";
            }else
            if(map2value="2"){
                document.getElementById('OverlayMap').src = "Img/000.png";
            }else
            if(map2value="3"){
                document.getElementById('OverlayMap').src = "Img/000.png";
            }else
            if(map2value="4"){
                document.getElementById('OverlayMap').src = "Img/000.png";
            }else
        }else
    }else
}
```

Selection menus are like this:

```
    <td>
        <select id="map1" name="map1">
            <option value="0">Please choose your map one</option>
            <option value="1">World Population</option>
            <option value="2">Scientific Research</option>
        </select>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="40">
    <td>
        <select id="blendmode" name="blendmode" >
            <option value="0">Please choose your blend mode</option>
            <option value="1">Add</option>
            <option value="2">Substract</option>
            <option value="3">Multiply</option>
            <option value="4">Divide</option>
        </select>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="40">
    <td>
        <select id="map2" name="map2">
            <option value="0">Please choose your map two</option>
            <option value="1">World Population</option>
            <option value="2">Scientific Research</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td width="250">
    <button onClick="javascript:ChangeOverlayMap(this.value)">Submit</button>
    </td>
```

and a place to put images:

```
   <img id="OverlayMap" src="Imgs/Blank.png" alt="" class="singlemap">
```

I have other JavaScript functions so i have to separate them up.

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help.

Comment: Comparisons in JavaScript must be done with either `==` or `===`. Your use of `=` in the if statements (e.g. `if(map1value="0")`) is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I forgot to mention that when I was clicking on the submit button(with values are all "0") it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: ChangeOverlayMap is not defined" and goes to 404. Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: Fun fact: JavaScript was named after [Java](https://www.java.com/) in order to make it more popular; this was a marketing ploy, but the languages are very dissimilar.